# Applicative asking for unexpected type

Tags: idris, applicative

I'm having difficulty implementing `Applicative` for my type. Here's `Functor`

```
data Connection : repr -> out -> Type where
  MkConnection : (repr -> ty) -> (ty -> out) -> Connection repr out

Functor (Connection repr) where
  map f (MkConnection get g) = MkConnection get $ f . g
```

If I write `Applicative` with a hole

```
Applicative (Connection repr) where
  pure x = ?rhs
```

I can type check to get

```
"src/Foo.idr" 94L, 4210C written
 0 a : Type
 0 repr : repr
   x : a
------------------------------
rhs : Connection repr a
```

A search gives no results. Indeed, if I add more detail

```
Applicative (Connection repr) where
  pure x = MkConnection ?get ?g
```

I get

```
"src/Foo.idr" 94L, 4223C written
Error: While processing right hand side of pure. When unifying Connection repr a and Connection repr a.
Mismatch between: Type and repr (implicitly bound at .../src/Foo.idr:94:5--94:34).

.../src/Foo.idr:94:14--94:34
    |
 94 |     pure x = MkConnection ?get ?g
    |
```

I would have thought I can implement that with

```
pure x = MkConnection (\r => ()) (\_ => x)
```

but I'm getting

```
"src/Foo.idr" 94L, 4235C written
Error: While processing right hand side of pure. When unifying Connection repr a and Connection repr a.
Mismatch between: Type and repr (implicitly bound at .../src/Foo.idr:94:5--94:47).

.../src/Foo.idr:94:14--94:47
    |
 94 |     pure x = MkConnection (\r => ()) (\_ => x)
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems to be interpreting `\r => ()` as a `Type -> something`

Comment: Does it help if you change the definition to `data Connection : Type -> Type -> Type where ...`?

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher ah, thanks. That was an obvious mistake. Works perfectly now